# Upload file to https site via PowerShell

Tags: powershell, https

I found this script. I want to automatically upload zip file to site but doesn't work..

```
$SourceFilePath = "C:\Users\Ulis\Desktop\logggz.zip"
$SiteAddress = "https://dev.loin.com/upload"
$URLDest = "{0}/{1}" -f ($SiteAddress, "logggz.zip")
$MyUsername = "ulis"
$MyPassword = "userAccSite"

Function Upload-File { 
    Param (
        [string]$File, 
        [string]$URI, 
        [string]$Dest,
        [string]$Username,
        [string]$Password
    )
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $WebClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)
    ("*** Uploading {0} file to {1} ***" -f ($File, $URI)) | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
    $WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, "PUT", $File)
} 

Upload-File -File $SourceFilePath -URI $SiteAddress -Dest $URLDest -Username $MyUsername -Password $MyPassword
```

But.. return this error:

```
Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "An exception occurred during a WebClient request."
At C:\Users\Ulis\Desktop\scriptStop.ps1:18 char:5
+     $WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, "PUT", $File)
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the host you're uploading to expecting you to use the ***PUT*** method as the default will be to use ***POST***?

If you're unsure, try to change:

```
$WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, "PUT", $File)
```

to

```
$WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, "POST", $File)
```

That may just do the trick, however, if not, you'll need to look into the exception details further to see exactly what's going on.

You should be able to obtain the a more accurate exception message by running the following (just run it after the exception occurs in the same PowerShell session and $message should give us further to go on):

```
$exception = $Error[0].Exception
$message = $exception.Message
while ($exception.InnerException) {
  $exception = $exception.InnerException
  $message += "`n" + $exception.Message
}
$message
```

Comment: Hei , I try PUT and POST and return this: 

Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."
The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Exception calling "UploadFile" with "3" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."
At line:18 char:5
+     $WebClient.UploadFile($Dest, "POST", $File) # or 'PUT'
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException

Comment: Okay, so if that same exception (_(405) Method Not Allowed_) happens for both PUT and POST requests, it seems as though the webserver isn't configured to allow HTTP uploads (using conventional methods anyway). Is the server you're uploading to something you manage yourself? If so, can you shed any light on how the script on the server end is written/setup?

Comment: Hello NiMux , unfortunatelly not. I try to capture https trace and I have: 
`
POST /uploadlog HTTP/1.1 Host: site.com:443 Accept: <...> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryP2... Sec-Fetch-Dest: document Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin Sec-Fetch-User: ?1 Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1  HTTP/1.1 302 Found Cache-Control: no-cache, private Connection: Keep-Alive Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Date: Mon, 28 Nov 2022 13:00:10 GMT Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100 Location: https://example.com/upload Server: Apache Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
`